# MATLAB: adding columns to an empty matrix only when condition is true

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary, mask

[image]I have a image (orig) and a corresponding binary mask (maskD) composed of vertical streaks/columns of values zero or one. I am trying to make a third matrix (streakTemp) composed of only those columns in the image which have a 1 value in the mask. I'm using the code below and for some reason its giving me as an output both the columns I'm looking for and then zero values where the mask value is 0...so my output has the same x length as my input image...it should be shorter with the mask values of zero excluded. Not sure what I'm doing wrong..any thoughts?  Thanks!

```
streakTemp=[];
for i=1:x
    if maskD(1,i)==1
        streakTemp(:,i)=orig(:,i); 
    end
end

imtool(streakTemp);
```

Comment: nah its all zeros and ones, attached now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant of your code should work:

```
streakTemp=[];
j=1;
for i=1:x
   if maskD(1,i)==1
      streakTemp(:,j)=orig(:,i); 
      j=j+1;
   end
end
```

The problem you have is that the `i` index always corresponds to the original matrix column, thus it won's skip the column even if the mask condition is not met.

Comment: Yup, this worked great. I tried something like this but switched an i or a j somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but my answer does the same in a single line, without a loop and extra variables, so it's faster, uses less overhead and is easier to read. Maybe you want to re-think what your accepted answer might be :)

Comment: @bers I agree.  Consulting Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ... where they talk about actually answering questions... the point where it talks about choosing an answer that's also good practice is very poignant.

Comment: Clearly @rayryeng's answer is more recommended, in terms of both code simplicity and efficiency.

Comment: @RaymondKwan If I had to choose though, I would choose this answer because this requires very little change to the OP's code which is what the OP was after.  In general, using logical indexing is the recommended approach. All facts aside, very nicely done.

Comment: @RaymondKwan: Clearly, @rayryeng's answer is essentially mine :) As to having an answer that requires as few changes as possible: If the purpose of an answer is to make non-efficient code even slower, then yes, this is the answer to chose. But I do not see why replacing the whole unnecessary loop by `streakTemp = orig(:, logical(maskD(1, :))` is a big change to the OP's code, either.

Comment: @bers Yes that answer is yours and I apologize for writing it... but as I said before, I got distracted with your loop code and I didn't realize that you were using the OP's code first followed by what you did.  If I actually saw it properly, I wouldn't have written my answer.

Comment: Oh, no need to apologize, really! I just wanted to mention that, this stuff happens all the time with easy to answer questions :)

Comment: @bers If it were up to me, your answer will be accepted, ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
orig  = reshape(1 : 20, 4, 5)
maskD = [1 0 0 1 1; 1 0 0 1 1; 1 0 0 1 1; 1 0 0 1 1]
mask1D = maskD(1, :)
x = 5;

streakTemp=[];
for i=1:x
    if maskD(1,i)==1
        streakTemp(:,i)=orig(:,i); 
    end
end
streakTemp

streakTemp2 = orig(:, logical(mask1D))
```

It outputs:

```
orig =

     1     5     9    13    17
     2     6    10    14    18
     3     7    11    15    19
     4     8    12    16    20


maskD =

     1     0     0     1     1
     1     0     0     1     1
     1     0     0     1     1
     1     0     0     1     1


mask1D =

     1     0     0     1     1


streakTemp =

     1     0     0    13    17
     2     0     0    14    18
     3     0     0    15    19
     4     0     0    16    20


streakTemp2 =

     1    13    17
     2    14    18
     3    15    19
     4    16    20
```

Here is more on [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/).
Note that your `maskD` does not have to be a matrix at all; you only need to store the first line, which is why I use `mask1D`.

Comment: I'm getting "index exceeds matrix dimensions" when I try this

Comment: I don't (in R2015b). In which line? What is the value of the variables at this point?

Comment: See my edit. You probably used your old, 2-D `maskD` instead of the 1-D version which I now call `mask1D`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using loops here.  Straight up logical indexing is totally fine for your purposes:

```
streakTemp = orig(:, maskD(1,:) == 1);
```

Remember that `maskD` is a mask that's the same size as your original image, so we only need to access the first row to do the check.  Simply put, this takes a look at all columns where `maskD` is equal to 1 then uses the corresponding locations to subsample from your `orig` matrix to create a new matrix that removes all columns that are not desired.

Comment: That's essentially what I wrote in my answer :) `logical(maskD)` will be faster that `maskD == 1`, though.

Comment: @bers Sorry I didn't see that as part of your answer.  I got distracted by you using loops where the more optimized answer simply was in the background. I wouldn't have wrote this if I noticed.  I would suggest you remove the code with loops so people don't get confused.... because I did.